# How to debug .NET Core w/ SSL in VS Code

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to debug an ASP.NET Core site in Visual Studio Code. Currently when I want to test the site under SSL I have to pull up full blown Visual Studio.

I have the `startup.cs` file configured to require `https` as well as a redirect configured if a non-secure request comes through, but this doesn't seem to have any effect when starting the project in VSC.

So, is there any way to configure an ASP.NET Core site to run under SSL when using Visual Studio Code?

**EDIT**

Also, just to clarify. If I remove the require https w/ redirect from the `startup.cs` file debugging in VSC works perfectly.

Comment: I assume you're using Kestrel for the VC version, and Kestrel does not support SSL (nor is recommended to expose it to Internet). The usual is to have a reverse proxy like NGINX to manage the SSL part.

Comment: @Gusman: That's not exactly true for ASP.NET Core 2.x. See [Kestrel topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) on ASP.NET Core docs. The docs state: _The most important reason for using a reverse proxy for edge deployments (exposed to traffic from the Internet) is security. The **1.x versions of Kestrel** don't have a full complement of defenses against attacks. This includes, but isn't limited to, appropriate timeouts, size limits, and concurrent connection limits._ also Kestrel in ASP.NET Core 2.x/.NET Core 2.x does support SSL too

Comment: Though there are still advantages of using nginx (easier handling, moving of encryption/decryption work to the loadbalancers, etc): (Trivia notes): Starting with ASP.NET Core 2.1, the ASP.NET Core application will be  (once again) directly hosted as in-process inside IIS for increased performance by avoid the local loopback to Kestrel. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/265 for 6x increased throughput

Comment: @Jared: Did you configure SSL? Like setting SSL certificate in your WebHostBuild method? Can you post your Program.cs/Startup.cs related code? See the linked document about Kestrel I commented on for Gusman, it also shows how to configure your own SSL certificates for kestrel

Comment: @Tseng It's hard to be updated with .net Core, there are so many changes from version to version... Just as a note, the 1.x version does not support full SSL, only TLS and it's use is totally discouraged.

Comment: @Tseng I will check this later. This will only ever see the light of day during development. I want to be able to leave the directives to redirect to and require ssl in my `startup.cs`, but have settings for development. I'll comment later if this works.